# C++ program execution time estimation on embedded system

Tags: c++, performance, embedded-linux, benchmarking

I have written a C++ algorithm on my laptop and I did some timing with this standard approach:

```
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  clock_t start = clock();

  // Algorithm ...

  clock_t end = clock();
  double time_s = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

What I am finally interested in is if this algorithm will be able to run at a specific frequency on an embedded development board (Raspberry, BeagleBone, Jetson TK1, Qualcomm DragonBoard,....). So, before buying one of the boards, I would like to know if my code will be fast enough on them.

Is  there an easy way for me to estimate what will be the execution time on one of these boards? It is enough for me to have a rough estimate.

Comment: I very much doubt it.

Comment: It's not only your code, but also the compiler and its settings, that determine the outcome. You'll often hear that this-and-that algorithm is better because it *can* be optimized. Doesn't mean the compiler *will* if it's not configured/implemented to do so... So there are probably too many factors to be sure beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO every program is different, can be optimized in different ways etc. If you have some specific code/program already wrote, you could ask, on some forum, people to run that program and give you the results. I think there'll be a lot of helpful people which'll help you.

If you're looking for general performance of these boards or don't want to give to someone your code/program, last thing that you can do is to look for some benchmarks over the internet.